# HexFile package R

Tags: r, hex, eviews

I am trying to import an eviews file (.wf1) into `R` with the `hexView` package.

Code:

```
file = readEViews(hexViewFile("eviewsr.wf1"),as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

Error message:

> Error in readBin(infile, what = "raw", n = nbytes) :    can only read
>   from a binary connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file,
>   "rb") :   file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using
>   the former

Anyone has any experience with this package?
Here is the documentation and I applied the code similarly to the documentation example:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexView/hexView.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `hexViewFile`:

```
file = readEViews("eviewsr.wf1")
```

Also AFAIK you don't need to include the `as.data.frame` because R will assume that it's true if you don't include it.